# How to change object attributes inside methods dynamically

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I have this question as I'm trying to make my program "better" :P

```
class GlobalVariables {

    int att1;
    int att2;
    int att2;...
```

I'm using that class as a way to handle pretty much every global value I will need in my program.

This class `GlobalVariables` contains a lot of attributes, each one of those its retrieved from a sensor and can be changed from `method3` which is a validations method to keep some of the values in a range.

In the Main class I have an Object of **another** class (lets say `class2`).

This objects (lets say `car`) has a method:

```
car.method(gl)
```

`gl` being an instance of `GlobalVariables`.

Now, inside method, I call `method2` and inside I call `method3` (all from `class2`).

```
this.method3 (int att1, int att2, int att3,)
this.method3 (int att2, int att3, int att1,)
this.method3 (int att3, int att1, int att2,)
```

At the moment, we have lots of calls of `method3` and the 3 parameters can be a combination of those sensor values so `att1` could be `att37` in a matter of speaking.

So the declaration of `method3` is like:

```
public void method3 (int n1, int n2, int n3){
     n3=n1+n2;
}
```

What should I do to change the `globalVariable.attXXX` when Java just lets us pass values by value.

I could of course make 2 more methods and call the corresponding method and using a SET, but I think it's pretty much what I'm trying to avoid.

When I say SET, I mean SETTER

Comment: Just return that value and assign on the calling site.

Comment: If those are **global** (something you must avoid in OO programming), then you could just write `gl.att1 = 1`. or something like that. Then you should change your method3 to: `public void method3( GlobalVariables g){ g.att3 = g.att1 + g.att2; }`.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  Please don't pursue this approach further, especially not if you discover reflection.   Either make them public or write getters and setters for each field.

Comment: Maybe, **just maybe** you are doing the wrong approach to solve a problem. It would be nice to understand your **real** problem (and code) is, so we could better guide you to another approach.

Comment: And, of course, you can make a setter and pass it (the setter method)

Comment: elazar Thought about that, I'm trying to find something better, but that's my "last shot". MiguelKVidal the global is an object i need to have some control values, can¿t do what you say as 2nd and 3rd call of method3 use the same values but in <> order. Thorb... being pub or using setters I can't know which method call is so i can't know into which assign it.

Comment: It’s not apparent what you mean by global variable. Most people are tempted to use global variables so they don’t have to pass things around. It is hard to see what problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: @NathanHughes are those edit sufficient or should I explain something else?

Comment: @Isidorito I don't understand your problems with setters. What are you trying to avoid? a setter+getter is a reference, and you don't need the getter here.

Comment: Anyway, I believe the answers so far exhaust the possibilities of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Using a setter method:

```
static void setAtt3(int x) { att3 = x; }

void method3(int a, int b, IntConsumer setter) {
    setter.accept(a + b);
}
```

call:

```
method3(att1, att2, GlobalVariables::setAtt3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are global (something you must avoid in OO programming), then you could just write `gl.att1 = 1`.

Then you should change your method3 to:

```
public void method3( GlobalVariables g)
{
    g.att3 = g.att1 + g.att2;
}
```

This, as it is, just only solve your problem to change the value of an object of another class.
Keep in mind all the comments you received and try a new approach to your problem.
If you really need to change the value of any attribute, the best approach would be a `setter`.

Based on your comment, I would suggest something like this:

```
public class GlobalVariables {
    private int x3;
    public void method3( int a, int b ) {
        x3 = a + b;
    }
}
```

Create getters and setters for your variables as needed. If you need to update another variable, like `x2`, then create a new method to do it for you.
If you don't, then you are breaking some rules. In this case, you are breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Using a setter would require to make 3 methods so in each one I change a different attribute or add another parameter with the name of the field to and make a switch, but keep in mind this is just an example, the real method I have has more code and the **method3** its called lot more times with different combinations of attributes.

Comment: Do you mean `void method( int v1, int v2, Object target )`? If so, then you probably are doing this the wrong way... Even though this is possible, as you can see in another answer and comments, try to avoid this... I will update my answer...